# HP laserjet p1006 stopped working after updates 

Tags: 12.04, hp, printing

I deleted the printer and installed hplip from Ubuntu software centre. Got error message:

> Stopped Backend/usr/lib/cups/backend/hp does not exist

I removed and reinstalled `hplip`.

Now the printer will only show as a USB connection and still doesn't work. The job appears as processing and then printer shows idle, but nothing happens.

Comment: Refer for [similar](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22048/usr-lib-cups-backend-hp-has-failed-with-an-hp-laserjet-p3005) error . If not try this [driver from their official site](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_p1006.html)

Answer (score 0):

As posted [in question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/159172/revisions)

> Reinstalled the foomatic files on spec and all is well. It's still a mystery to me though.

Answer (score 0):

I've been around this block a dozen times.  It kept failing this time until I realized that you have to:

sudo hp-toolbox

so it has the permissions to install the driver.